# How to detect whether users have accepted terms?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I am writing a PHP and MYSQL script that will check whether a user has accepted the terms and conditions or not. In the databse every current user that has signed up is set to "unaccepted". When they log in the first page that they are directed to should have a scirpt on it that detects whether or not the status of the `tos` column in the `users` table is set to "accepted" or "unaccepted". If it is accepted they can continue, and if it is not they they will be forced to go to a page and accept them before they can continue to use the rest of my site. This is the code so far but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions help.

```
<?php

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$connect = mysql_connect('**', '**', '**', '**');
if (!$connect) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('**')) 
{
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$toschecker = mysql_query("SELECT `tos` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
if (!$toschecker) 
{
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($connect);
$unaccepted='unaccepted';

if ($toschecker === $unaccepted)
{
    header('Location: accepttos.php');
}    
?>
```

For some reason this isn't directing them to the accepttos.php page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql_query is returning a resource (NOT the value of `tos`). there is no point comparing that to anything

Comment: Please get in the habit of sanitizing your inputs you probably should have `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);` but really you should use `PDO` with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change MySQL to MySQLi. Explanations are in the comments.

```
<?php

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$connect = mysqli_connect('Host', 'Username', 'Password', 'Database');
if (!$connect) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$toschecker = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `tos` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"); /* SELECT TOS COLUMN */

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($toschecker)) 
{
    $tos = $row['tos']; /* STORE TO A VARIABLE THE FETCHED TOS */
}

$unaccepted = 'unaccepted';

if ($tos == $unaccepted) /* COMPARE THE TOS VARIABLE IF UNACCEPTED */
{
    header('Location: accepttos.php');
}

else {
    header('Location: acceptedTOS.php'); /*  IF TOS IS ACCEPTED. CHANGE THE LOCATION */
}

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: Which part of the webpage do I need to put these in? Is it in the <head>?

Comment: No! Just part of the body.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to be detecting the "else" rather than the "if".

Comment: Maybe because the data is not unaccepted. Check the username's TOS on your database.

Comment: Hmmm, nope. It is set to "unaccepted" in the database. Even if I change the statement to if == 'accepted', it still goes to the else statement.

Comment: Have you checked your $username=$_SESSION['username']? Where did you get it. Did you set it with the right name? Try echoing the $tos and see what's inside this variable.

Comment: If I echo $tos nothing appears, however if I echo $username then the correct username appears. In addition if I echo $toschecker, nothing appears.

Comment: So the problem is the $tochecker=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `tos` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"); Check thoroughly this line.

Comment: When I run the query in PHPMyAdmin replacing $username with a username in ' marks it returns "unaccepted" with the `tos` column, with the right user. This is strange haha. Thanks for your help this far.

Comment: I got it mate. In your suggestion: while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($tochecker)){ should be while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($toschecker)){ Thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: @user2934716 When editing, please don't add comments on the post to the body of the post. To annotate or explain your edit, use the "Edit summary" box.

Comment: @user2934716 What's the difference?

Comment: In your suggestion: while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($tochecker)){ should be while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($toschecker)){. toschecker instead of tochecker

Comment: @user2934716 But i based it on your post, $toschecker

Answer (score 0):

`$toschecker` is a resource , try the following under the `mysql_query` line to see the result of your query, which you can use to redirect accepttos.php etc..

```
if( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($toschecker)) {
    var_export($row['tos']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the information in the fields of your database. Here is an example.

```
$toschecker = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($toschecker);

$tos = $row['tos'];

if($tos == 'accepted'){
     // go to regular page
}else {
     // go to accept terms page
}
```